# The "Using" keyword to call base class constructor

Tags: c++, using

I have the following base class

```
class Grammateas
{
 public:
 Grammateas(std::string name):_name(name){};
  virtual ~Grammateas(){};
 private:
  std::string _name;
};
```

and the following derived class

```
class Boithos final : public Grammateas
{
 public:
  //using Grammateas::Grammateas;
  Boithos(int hours):Grammateas("das"),_hours(hours){};
  virtual ~Boithos(){};
 private:
  int _hours;
};
```

I want to use the Base class constructor to create object like this

```
   Boithos Giorgakis(5); //works
   Boithos Giorgakis("something"); //Bug
```

I read that I can use the using keyword but when I try to use it like

```
   using Grammateas::Grammateas;
```

The compiler return a message

> error: ‘Grammateas::Grammateas’ names constructor

Can you help me understand the using keyword with constructors?

Comment: It's for *inheriting* constructors...

Comment: Finally I found that this feature is only avaliable at GCC 4.8
I have gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code - with the `using Grammateas::Grammateas;` uncommented - should work. (But beware: the inherited constructor would leave `_hours` uninitialized.)

Inheriting constructors through `using`-declarations is a new feature in C++11. Maybe your compiler does not yet support this feature or has problems combining inherited constructors and other overloads.  (If it accepts the `final` specifier, it appears to be set up correctly to compile C++11 in the first place.)

Comment: I found that this feature is only avaliable at GCC 4.8.
I have GCC (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2.
It's ok with the final keyword and -std=c++11