# Creating own exceptions (2 ways) c++

Tags: c++, exception

I was asked to create custom exceptions by inheriting from standard library std::logic_error exception. Firstly, I tried to do things by the book:

```
class CustomException: public std::logic_error
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "Exception raised";
  }
};
```

But then my colleague, who was also given this task, showed me another way to handle this:

```
class CustomException:public std::logic_error {
 using std::logic_error::logic_error;
public:
    const static std::string ExceptionText;
};
```

Beside the fact that the message of exception needs to be passed differently, what is the main difference between those two? Specifically I do not know what using statement does in the second option.

Comment: You may find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772445/the-using-keyword-to-call-base-class-constructor) informative.

Comment: The using statement is getting the constructors from the base class logic_error. There is no real difference it is kinda like say `int i = 0; while(i<5) i++;`

Comment: @JakeFreeman you mean no difference other than one overrides `what()` and the other has an unused string kicking around?

Comment: Your colleague's version seems to have a redundant static member.

Comment: @UKMonkey I mean substantive difference in performance etc.

Comment: @JakeFreeman The `using` is to get the base class constructors. Except it seems to make them private, so it seems a bit useless.

Comment: I think this is too broad without more realistic context. Neither exception really does anything useful, so it's hard or nonsensical to decide between them. One returns the same message every time, basically defeating the point of having any message, and the other has a static member that would presumably return the same message every time if anyone bothered to set or use it.

Comment: @juanchopanza - It doesn't make them private. The access specifier under which the using declaration appears is ignored when c'tors are inherited.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well that's interesting! C++ is full of little surprises.

Comment: Beware adding a member that could throw to your exception class. See the [Boost guidelines](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same.

In your colleagues version:

```
    // This does nothing.
    // Delete it and the rest of the class is unchanged.
    const static std::string ExceptionText;


class CustomException:public std::logic_error {
    // This line basically inherits the base class constructor(s)
    // Which allows you to construct your exception like others.
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};
```

You can think of the above as short hand for:

```
class CustomException: public std::logic_error {
    public:
        CustomException(std::string const& emsg)
            : logic_error(emsg)
        {}
        CustomException(char const* emsg)
            : logic_error(emsg)
        {}
        // And a couple of more
};
```

Note: the `what()` function on the base class will return a reference to the message you passed at the beginning.

Another alternative (if you want to keep your original message).

```
class CustomException: public std::logic_error
{
    public:
        CustomException()
            : logic_error("Exception raised")
        {}
        // The default "what()" will return the above message.
};
```